# Can't get PDFTK to run in SQL Server using xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, pdftk

I am trying to do a simple `xp_cmdshell` with pdftk but get the same error every time.

```
xp_cmdshell 'pdftk "\\server\Database Documents\temp.pdf" "\\server\Database Documents\temp2.pdf" cat output "\\server\Database Documents\result.pdf"'
```

but I get this error:

> 'pdftk' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have tried adding quotes in various combinations. I have created a `.bat` file to call using the same command line. I have tried prefacing with `cmd c/`. Nothing works. Both the cmd line and the bat file work fine when run manually but using `xp_cmdshell` it errors every time. This seems like such a simple task but I have spent way too much time trying to get it to work with so success.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Use a fully-qualified path for the program `pdftk`, or add its folder to the system path and reboot the machine.

Comment: `xp_cmdshell` is run as the SQL Server service account, is `pdtfk` added to that account's `PATH$`?

Comment: Thank you David Browne -- that is the answer.    I really appreciate it.